# get "FileVersion" from a file that will not be installed

Tags: wix

A well known trick to get a variable based on a file file version is

```
  <?define ProductVersion = !(bind.FileVersion.filProductVersion) ?>
```

where

```
  <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="MyCG">
            <Component Id="cmpabc" Directory="INSTALLDIR" Guid="YOUR-GUID-HERE">
                <File Id="filProductVersion" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.MyRootFolder)\fileIAmGoingToInstall.dll" />
            </Component>
```

Is there anyway to set a variable based on the file version of a file I do NOT want to install?

I've tried this:

MyWxs.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <Fragment>
  <Binary Id="binaryProductVersionId" SourceFile="$(var.MyRootFolder)\FileIDoNotWantToInstall.dll" />
  </Fragment>


</Wix>
```

MyWxi.wxi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
      <?define ProductVersion = !(bind.FileVersion.binaryProductVersionId) ?>
</Include>
```

But I get:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unresolved bind-time variable !(bind.FileVersion.binaryProductVersionId).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to place a condition inside the component that always be false.

```
        <Component Id="cmpabc" Directory="INSTALLDIR" Guid="YOUR-GUID-HERE">
            <File Id="filProductVersion" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.MyRootFolder)\fileIAmGoingToInstall.dll" />
            <Condition>IGNORE = "0"</Condition>
        </Component>
```

where IGNORE can be a property or use variable $(var.IGNORE)

Comment: BRILLIANT!  I used "<Condition>0=1</Condition>" to make it short and simple.